# Using selectors with smart/dumb components in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, reselect

Say I have a top most smart component called Forecast that looks like this:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    dates: state.getIn(['forecast', 'dates']),
    isFetching: state.getIn(['forecast', 'isFetching'])
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  fetchForecast
})(Forecast));
```

Which wraps a Forecast component like this:

```
import { getSummary, getDayForecast } from '../selectors/selectors';
export default class Forecast extends Component {

  render() {
    const { dates, isFetching } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className="row">
        {dates.map(date => (
          <Weather
            key={date}
            date={date}
            getSummary={getSummary}
            getDayForecast={getDayForecast}
          />
       ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

Here I am passing 2 selectors as props into a `Weather` component.  The selectors look like this:

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';
import moment from 'moment';
import { fromJS } from 'immutable';

const getDay = (state, key) => state.getIn(['forecast', 'forecast']).find(x => x.get('id') === key);

export const getSummary = createSelector(
  [getDay],
  (day => {
    const firstPeriod = day.get('periods').first();

    return fromJS({
      date: day.get('date'),
      outlook: firstPeriod.get('outlook'),
      icon: firstPeriod.get('icon')
    });
  })
);

export const getDayForecast = createSelector(
  [getDay],
  (day) => day.get('periods').map(period => fromJS({id: period.get('id') }))
);
```

I don't have to pass these selectors down as props, I could easily just reference them in the weather component but I am confused as to how I would use these selectors in the Weather component as the Weather component is also dumb and won't have any reference to state.  I only want 1 container or smart component at the top which the child components call or get props passed down.

The only way I can see of making this work is to have an intermediatary `WeatherContainer` component that looks something like this:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import Weather from '../components/Weather';

import { getSummary, getDayForecast } from '../selectors/selectors';

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  return {
    summary: getSummary(state, ownProps.date),
    detail: getDayForecast(state, ownProps.date)
  };
}

export default(connect(mapStateToProps,{}))(Weather);
```

And I would call like this:

```
    {dates.map(date => (
      <WeatherContainer
         key={date}
         date={date}
         getSummary={getSummary}
         getDayForecast={getDayForecast}
         />
    ))}
```

This seems completely wrong to have to create a container component like this.

How can I make use of selectors in dumb components or how can I pass them down as props baring in mind that they also need reference to the state?

Comment: Your selectors return `Immutable` objects which is overkill. It's also less performant and harder to use than plain objects. Think of `props` in React-Redux context as a temporary variable. It's immutable but there's no need for enforcement or management.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `WeatherContainer` `mapStateToProps` you use your selectors but you're still passing them down as props. This is not necessary.

Besides that, you should know that creating your container `WeatherContainer` is the right way to go about things. You should *never* give a selector to a component. They should always be used in `mapStateToProps`. React-Redux will reevaluate this when state changes and will tell React to update your components whenever the result is different. This is a very important point. If you just grab the state inside a component, whether using a selector or not, then React-Redux **doesn't know** you're using this data and **won't we able to tell React to rerender** when this data changes.

Now, a lot of people are confused on this matter. There are dumb components, which just display stuff, and container components, which *do* stuff, like make API calls or implement functionality of sorts. But when you take a dumb component and `connect` it to Redux, then this doesn't make for a smart or container component. It still only displays stuff. Even if you use `mapDispatchToProps` to feed it some event listeners, this still doesn't really make the component smart. It could become smart if it contains significant code in `mapStateToProps` or `mapDispatchToProps` I guess. But such is life. The line between these things is just blurry.

The Redux Way is to connect everything that needs data. You can certainly pass data down to children, just as in plain React, but you create a more performant app by connecting components. Still, it's up to you to decide. But it is still important that anywhere you grab data from the store, it should be put inside a `mapStateToProps` so React-Redux can keep an eye on the data. You can safely pass it from a parent to a child as long as the data came from `mapStateToProps`.

This means passing selectors to children is a no-no. Also, where's the child going to get the state to pass as a parameter to the selectors? It doesn't work well so it's not a good idea. Note that whenever you `connect` a component, you're not creating an entirely new component. Is just a simple wrapper. It should contain very little code in very few lines. This should not give you pause. Just go for it. `connect` those components.

I should also mention that you can connect your `Weather` component directly inside the `weather.js` file. Unless you're going to reuse it, there's not much need to keep the unconnected component around. For testing you can `export` the unconnected component with a named export. If later on you decide you need to reuse the`Weather` component, you can always easily separate the component and the connect call into separate files.

Comment: What if I had a master/child scenario when clicking on a parent component made an async call to fetch and display the child records for that parent.  Would selectors be useful for that?

I only want to make the call the first time and not thereafter

Comment: No. That's a no-no because you'll want to dispatch an action to put that data into the Redux store and let Redux do any necessary rerendering *for* you, of child components or siblings or wherever. This is part of benefits: Anything that depends on this data, now or in in a future version of your app, gets updated, guaranteed. It's the *main benefit* of Redux: Every part of the app agrees on the data. And this really doesn't depend on how many calls you want to make to an API or backend or friend nor when nor how.

Comment: Selectors are to used to do grab data from the store. The reason to use selectors is so that when the store shape changes, the selector, and only the selector, can be modified to return the right data. Selectors can also call other (parent) selectors, so that if you move state slices around, you may only need to change a single selector. Sometimes selectors can also format the data, but then they are really formatters. Still, [Reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect), or other generic [memoizers](https://gist.github.com/addyosmani/1225243), will work just fine with formatters as well.

Comment: something beyond todos?

Comment: extremely helpful explanation BTW

Comment: Maybe [this one](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples/async) or [this one](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples/real-world)? Or see [here](https://github.com/xgrommx/awesome-redux/blob/master/examples/README.md) for some more examples.